# How to scrape a website that has a difficult table to read (pandas & beautiful soup)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from https://www.seethroughny.net/payrolls/110681345 but the table is difficult to deal with.

I have tried many things.

```
import pandas as pd
import ssl
import csv

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context


calls_df = pd.read_html("https://www.seethroughny.net/payrolls/110681345", header=0)
print(calls_df)

calls_df.to_csv("calls.csv", index=False)
```

I would like to parse this into a csv file and I am index matching this with another dataset.

Comment: I'd recommend opening up the dev console in the browser and seeing if first the payrolls are being retrieved from an endpoint in json before attempting to scrape it directly from the site. Failing that, if the sites dynamic, get the source via selenium, parse the data via beautifulsoup and then into a CSV format :)

Comment: Why is this table difficult to deal with? Simply use beautifulsoup: first lookup for the table, then lookup for thead inside this table to grab data inside <th>. Then get the rest from <tbody>.

Comment: Was your question answered?

Answer (score 2):

There is a json response containing the html. It seems that something blocks requests at random points in entire all results loop version at end

Single page version where you change the `current_page` value to the appropriate page number.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.seethroughny.net/tools/required/reports/payroll?action=get'
headers = {

  'Accept' : 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' ,
  'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0',
'Referer' : 'https://www.seethroughny.net/payrolls/110681'
}

data = {

  'PayYear[]' : '2018',
  'BranchName[]' : 'Villages',
 'SortBy' : 'YTDPay DESC',
 'current_page' : '0',
 'result_id' : '110687408',
 'url' : '/tools/required/reports/payroll?action=get',
 'nav_request' : '0'  

}

r = requests.post(url,  headers = headers, data = data).json()
soup = bs(r['html'], 'lxml')

results = []

for item in soup.select('tr:nth-child(odd)'):
    row = [subItem.text for subItem in item.select('td')][1:]
    results.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

---

All pages version (work in progress as currently request can fail to return json at varying points in loop despite delay). Seems improved with @sim's suggestion of swapping out user-agents.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
import random


ua = ['Mozilla/5.0',
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36',
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36',
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'
   ]


url = 'https://www.seethroughny.net/tools/required/reports/payroll?action=get'
headers = {

  'Accept' : 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' ,
  'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0',
'Referer' : 'https://www.seethroughny.net/payrolls/110681'
}

data = {

  'PayYear[]' : '2018',
  'BranchName[]' : 'Villages',
 'SortBy' : 'YTDPay DESC',
 'current_page' : '0',
 'result_id' : '110687408',
 'url' : '/tools/required/reports/payroll?action=get',
 'nav_request' : '0'  

}

results = []
i = 0
with requests.Session() as s:
    retries = Retry(total=5,
                backoff_factor=0.1,
                status_forcelist=[ 500, 502, 503, 504 ])

    s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

    while len(results) < 1000: #total:
        data['current_page'] = i
        data['result_id'] = str(int(data['result_id']) + i)

        try:
            r = s.post(url, headers = headers, data = data).json()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            time.sleep(2)
            headers['User-Agent'] =  random.choice(ua)
            r = s.post(url, headers = headers, data = data).json()
            continue
        soup = bs(r['html'], 'lxml')

        for item in soup.select('tr:nth-child(odd)'):
            row = [subItem.text for subItem in item.select('td')][1:]
            results.append(row)
        i+=1
```

---

@Sim's version:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url = 'https://www.seethroughny.net/tools/required/reports/payroll?action=get'

headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Referer' : 'https://www.seethroughny.net/payrolls/110681'
}

data = {
    'PayYear[]' : '2018',
    'BranchName[]' : 'Villages',
    'SortBy' : 'YTDPay DESC',
    'current_page' : '0',
    'result_id' : '110687408',
    'url' : '/tools/required/reports/payroll?action=get',
    'nav_request' : '0'  
}

results = []

i = 0

def get_content(i):
    while len(results) < 15908:
        print(len(results))
        data['current_page'] = i
        headers['User-Agent'] = ua.random
        try:
            r = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = data).json()
        except Exception:
            time.sleep(1)
            get_content(i)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r['html'], 'lxml')

        for item in soup.select('tr:nth-child(odd)'):
            row = [subItem.text for subItem in item.select('td')][1:]
            results.append(row)
        i+=1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ua = UserAgent()
    get_content(i)
```

Comment: I get the following error: File "payroll.py", line 32, in <module>
    for item in soup.select('tr:nth-child(odd)'):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1528, in select
    'Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.')
NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: you need the latest bs4 i.e. 4.7.1 I'm afraid as that has soup sieve

Comment: Lovely to c u @SIM. Yes... I am not sure that id makes a difference but I have been playing with a script that simply adds i to the id by adding in data['result_id'] = str(int(data['result_id']) + i)

Comment: My real sticking point at present is why r = s.post line is failing at different points.... which is usually indicative of blocking etc but I have seen a 404 pop up despite requests being valid if run as a single request with the same page number.

Comment: I also need to extract rather than hard core the end point for results count but that’s a quick fix

Comment: Thank you. Still new to python so trying out different things. I’ll have a look at the user agent bit. I guess I could stick that in via a try except

Comment: Downloaded the newest beautiful soup. This website is really difficult.

Comment: What do you mean? The download site or SO? If I have made something difficult I apologise.

Comment: sorry - meant the website we are working with not bs

Comment: @SIM Interesting I randomly selected user-agent from a list and it worked once. Then back to same problem. Current failing attempt which worked once (messy!) https://pastebin.com/JAQAEcup

Comment: much tidier. I get a series of error messages unfortunately though it does keep running e.g. socket.timeout: timed out and fake_useragent.errors.FakeUserAgentError: Maximum amount of retries reached. It hit 15800  for me.

Comment: @sim You should post as answer :-)

Comment: The one I pastebin linked?